# Sending escape key to Popen subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm using a program that has a known bug where it tries to open a non-existent XML on startup. The error causes an alert dialog box to open. It's easily closed by pushing the escape key.

This approach works perfect:

```
ESCAPE_KEY = b'0x1b'
subprocess.run(PROGRAM_EXE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                   input=ESCAPE_KEY)
```

However, it would make life much easier if I could use Popen so I could kill the process after I am done with it.

This doesn't work:

```
ESCAPE_KEY = b'0x1b'
p = subprocess.Popen(PROGRAM_EXE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                   stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate(ESCAPE_KEY)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: but you want to kill the process if there's an error? when do you want to kill it? what "doesn't work" and why the `run` approach isn't satisfactory?

Comment: I want to kill it when the process is done executing, which I will check for externally. That doesn't affect what the question is about.
Doesn't work means the dialog box doesn't disappear, which is the goal of the question. Again, run isn't satisfactory because I have no control over the process. All of these things are answered in the question.

Comment: The docs imply that all `run` with an `input` parameter does is to call `p.communicate(input)` (and store the output). And if you look at [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/subprocess.py#L403), that's exactly what it does (modulo some error-handling cleanup, which doesn't sound relevant). So, it's hard to guess how `communicate` could "not work".

Comment: @moto But calling `communicate` doesn't give you any more control over the process than calling `run`. Either way, it doesn't return until the process has finished, so there's nowhere for you to run any code that does anything useful with that `p`.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you @abarnert I was thinking it would be easier to do, `p.terminate()` rather than have to search for the process using `psutil`

Comment: Well, you can do that if you, e.g., pass a timeout, or do the `communicate` in a separate thread, or using one of the asyncio subprocess wrappers, etc. But just calling `communicate` and waiting for it doesn't buy you much.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you! @abarnert

Comment: "I want to kill it when the process is done executing": you don't need that when the process is done executing...

Comment: It's an OCR GUI program, not a command line or script. It doesn't exit automatically. If it is left running it will keep looking for new files to OCR @Jean-FrançoisFabre